# Axios GET request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, http-status-code-404

I am trying to build (with `vue.js`) a blog/articles app which uses `axios` to request data from my `db.json` file with a `get request`. I want it to show the data from that article once it has been clicked on from the main articles list ==> I use the `id prop` so that it knows which article's data to get. Here I call my get request (the get request is in another file, keep reading).

```
ArticleShow.vue
<script>
import APIService from "@/APIService.js";
export default {
  props: ["id"],    // "id" has been passed as a prop when I import this file to its parent
  data() {
    return {
      article: {}
    };
  },
  created() {
    APIService.getArticle(this.id).then(response => {
      this.article = response.data;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

This is the axios GET request that I use (it's inside the APIService.js file)

```
APIService.js
import axios from "axios";

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
});

export default {
  getArticle(id) {
    return apiClient.get("/articles/" + id);
  }
}
```

I thought this code would work, but in my browser I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/articles/undefined 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:62)
```

I tried catching the error, but I couldn't get any useful information about where it was coming from and how I could fix it. I figured it might be the `id prop` that was causing the issue but not sure. In the parent of the `ArticleShow` component I define the `id prop` when displaying `ArticleShow` in a router-link.

```
ArticleCard.vue
<router-link
      class="article-link"
      :to="{ name: 'ArticleShow', params: { id: article.id } }"
      :article="this.article"
    >
```

And then again in the parent of `Articlecard.vue` (the previous component)

```
Home.vue
<ArticleCard
      v-for="article in articles"   // I imported *articles* from the vuex store
      :key="article.id"
      :article="article"
      class="ArticleCard"
></ArticleCard>
```

Still not sure if the `id prop` is really the root of the problem here. Anyway, please help if you can on this issue as it has gone on for quite a while, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a 404 or a connection refused? Your title and body disagree with each other and they are very different errors.

Comment: Sorry, wrong error. I have corrected it now, this is the error that I get in the browser console. I think the id prop may be the issue, because in the error message it calls it **.../undefined** but I don't see why.

Answer (score -1):

Error 404 means this URL doesn't exist: `http://localhost:5000/articles/undefined`

So this means you haven't passed any `id` prop to `ArticleShow` component

Comment: Yes, but I followed the path of the id prop and it all seems to make sense. Not sure where the error occurs and why it can't identify the id :(

Comment: @MattReid Just try to <ArticleShow :id="1" /> and check devtools network tab for example